# AddAttachment PHPmailer, email sended in blank

Tags: phpmailer, attachment, roundcube

let me put my problem, i hope someone can helpme.

I have a system to send my envoices using phpmailler, so when I send an email with AddAttachment I receive a email without show it body, when i send an email without an AddAttachment i receive normaly.

Let me show you:

**A Code from email with AddAttachment**

```
Return-path: <financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br>
Envelope-to: financeiro@codetek.com.br
Delivery-date: Fri, 19 May 2017 11:12:00 -0300
Received: from server01.heytec.com.br ([162.144.222.173]:36833 helo=www.heytec.com.br)
    by server01.heytec.com.br with esmtpa (Exim 4.85)
    (envelope-from <financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br>)
    id 1dBidM-0007MI-GB
    for financeiro@codetek.com.br; Fri, 19 May 2017 11:12:00 -0300
Date: Fri, 19 May 2017 11:12:00 -0300
To: financeiro@codetek.com.br
From: CT Informatica <financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br>
Subject: Sua Fatura Chegou!
Message-ID: <7c04d9e16a4d9a705b436f34c72b64ca@www.heytec.com.br>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer [version 1.73]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1From: CT Informatica <financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br>
Reply-To: financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="b1_7c04d9e16a4d9a705b436f34c72b64ca"
X-From-Rewrite: unmodified, already matched

--b1_7c04d9e16a4d9a705b436f34c72b64ca
Content-Type: text/html; charset = "iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<table style="border: 1px solid #33679a; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 16px; color: #1b1a17; height: 582px;" width="812" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr><td>MY SIMPLE HTML</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

--b1_7c04d9e16a4d9a705b436f34c72b64ca
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="boleto-1253172.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="boleto-1253172.pdf"

BLA BLA BLA PDF Encoding TEXT FROM PDF


--b1_7c04d9e16a4d9a705b436f34c72b64ca--
```

**A CODE WITHOUT AddAttachment**

```
Return-path: <financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br>
Envelope-to: financeiro@codetek.com.br
Delivery-date: Fri, 19 May 2017 11:33:54 -0300
Received: from server01.heytec.com.br ([162.144.222.173]:37764 helo=www.heytec.com.br)
    by server01.heytec.com.br with esmtpa (Exim 4.85)
    (envelope-from <financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br>)
    id 1dBiyX-0003Fd-Qd
    for financeiro@codetek.com.br; Fri, 19 May 2017 11:33:53 -0300
Date: Fri, 19 May 2017 11:33:53 -0300
To: financeiro@codetek.com.br
From: CT Informatica <financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br>
Subject: Sua Fatura Chegou!
Message-ID: <659d0adfa80994b156e9803bb3f84884@www.heytec.com.br>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer [version 1.73]
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1From: CT Informatica <financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br>
Reply-To: financeiro@ctinformatica.com.br
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
X-From-Rewrite: unmodified, already matched

<table style="border: 1px solid #33679a; font-family: Calibri; font-size: 16px; color: #1b1a17; height: 582px;" width="812" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr><td>MY SIMPLE HTML</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Lookslike when I put the AddAttachment in my code i have a problem.
when I go check my email received i got[image]

nothing, even the Attachment I can´t see.

check my send code

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
                $headers .= "From: $ln_letter[car_remetente] <$ln_letter[car_fromemail]>\n";     
                $headers .= "Reply-To: $ln_letter[car_fromemail]\n";

                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                $mail->SetLanguage("br", "language/");


                $mail->From = $ln_letter[car_fromemail]; 
                $mail->FromName = $ln_letter[car_remetente];
                $mail->Host = "mail.heytec.com.br";
                $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
                $mail->AddAddress($destinatario);
                $mail->AddCustomHeader($headers);


                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Body = $body; 

                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username =  $ln_letter[car_fromemail];
                $mail->Password =  $senha_email;

                $mail->AddAttachment($arrayanexos[$i]);

                $mail->Send()
```

I have no idea what it is this problem =(
and sorry about the english.

Comment: Here's a giveaway: `X-Mailer: PHPMailer [version 1.73]`. That is a very, very old version from 2005! Go [get the latest from Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and try again.

Comment: I SOLVED! Just remove the Custom Header, but i dont know why it does that

Comment: Well do that too - PHPMailer handles headers for you - read what the function does rather than just stuffing random guesses into it.

Comment: @DaniloRibeiro I am not even sending custom headers still it shows blank email as email body while using AddAttachment method else it shows HTML in email body any ideas?